# Why PHP doesn't run in Apache?

Tags: apache-httpd, php, elementary-os

I'm using Elementary OS and Apache.

What I did? I installed Apache 2 and I went to http://127.0.0.1/ to check if Apache was online, that's ok. I saw the **Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page**, I thought Apache 2 was ok and I could start to use HTML5, CSS3, JS and PHP.

I understood I couldn't, I tried to create a file HTML5 & CSS3, that was nice, when I tried to use PHP, It didn't work.

It doesn't give any error, just PHP doesn't work.

When I open http://127.0.0.1/index.php, It returns me:

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

It returns the code like if index.php would be a .txt file.

Here's my terminal log.

```
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ ls
index.html
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ nano test.htm
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ sudo nano test.htm
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ ls
index.html  test.htm
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ sudo nano test.htm
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ sudo nano file.css
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ sudo nano test.htm
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ sudo nano index.php
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ sudo nano test.htm
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ ls
file.css  index.html  index.php  test.htm
matt@matt:/var/www/html$ nano index.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you have to install php separately. `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` or similar should do the trick in most cases.
Probably you might need to enable the plugin with `a2enmod php5`